# Simple sheet music use case in Easyscore/Vexflow

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to render a very simple chord like so:

[image: chord]

I tried to do

```
score.notes('(C#5/q B4 A4 G#4)')
```

as demonstrated here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gcrb86fk/38/

But I get `IncompleteVoice: Voice does not have enough notes` in the console. Is there any easy way to do this straightforward use case? Or another js library?

Answer (score 1):

`'(C#5/q B4 A4 G#4)'` This is defining one chord that is one quarter note in length.

`'C#5/q, B4, A4, G#4'` One solution is to expand the chord into 4 individual quarter notes.

`'(C#5 B4 A4 G#4)/q, B4, A4, G#4'` Another solution is to add 3 more quarter notes to the voice.

EDIT:

`'(C#5 B4 A4 G#4)/1'` One chord and one chord alone.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it as a chord and a chord alone

Comment: @DaraJava Updated with a single chord solution.  If you need it to not be a whole note you need to change the signature.

Comment: Haha thank you again, but I still need it to be any one of a whole note, half note, quarter, etc. I just don't see a way to do this!

Comment: And I mean without the time signature being visible. I think I will go about it a hacky way, just put 3 dummy notes there and crop the resulting div

Comment: https://github.com/0xfe/vexflow/wiki/The-VexFlow-Tutorial I think this has some examples of what you are looking for.  The measure right about `Step 3: All About Modifiers` is a good example.   I think anyways.  We are moving beyond what I know of this program! Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue at https://stackoverflow.com/q/56614387/958373 and wonder if the code is wrong or the notes are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill the whole measure, which means you need to make it last four quarters long (one whole note).  This is done using "w" for Whole Note.

```js
score.voice(score.notes('(C4 E4 G4 Bb4)/w')),
```